# Xhtml validator error "not reserved name"

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm new to XHTML and I keep getting this error and can't find the solution anywhere.

Here's the error:
[error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDK2B.png)

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//project//test.xhtml">
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>Tools</title>
  <link href="oof.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css">
  </head>
   <body>
    <div class="page">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE html public "-//project//test.xhtml">` is not an XHTML Doctype.

The specific error you get is because an identifier has to be `PUBLIC` or `SYSTEM` and it is case sensitive.

The Doctype needs to reference the DTD you are validating against, not an XHTML document.

Most XHTML documents will use this Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

However, there is little point in using XHTML 1.0 in 2018. You would probably be better off using HTML 5 instead.

If you are using the XML serialisation of HTML 5, then you wouldn't use a Doctype at all.

Most people don't get any benefit from using XML though, and would be better off writing HTML instead. That uses the Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

… and then only for historical reasons to trigger Standards mode in browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot of errors in your syntax.

- LINK tag is a self closing tag.
- DOCTYPE html public "...." defines some info. [Read about it here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)
- Every opening tag has a closing tag

Here's what it should look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//project//test.xhtml">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tools</title>
    <link href="oof.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't treat answers as if they're forum replies, that's what comments are for. I've cleaned up your answer to reflect this.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html public "-//project//test.xhtml">` — You haven't fixed the error that the error message is about!

Comment: And the xmlns is missing.

Comment: in place of `<!DOCTYPE html public "-//project//test.xhtml">` he can use simply `<!DOCTYPE html>` to get the work done.....